# Ayuda con ejercicio en JS

Tags: javascript, array, diccionarios

Buenas tardes espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, tenia que hacer un ejercicio en el que almacene las cartas de un mazo,las separe en cartas negras y cartas rojas, despues sacar las cartas rojas y pares e imprimir la ultima carta, todo de acuerdo al poco conocimiento que tengo, soy un proyecto de arepndiz y usando la consola del navegador. Con lo que pude lo hice de esta manera  :

```html
var cartas = ["1c","2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","10c","11c","12c","1d","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","10d","11d","12d","1t","2t","3t","4t","5t","6t","7t","8t","9t","10t","11t","12t","1p","2p","3p","4p","5p","6p","7p","8p","9p","10p","11p","12p"]
undefined
cartasrojas = []
[]
cartasnegras = []
[]
for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartas[i][1] === "c" || cartas[i][1] === "d" || cartas[i][2] === "c" || cartas[i][2] === "d"){
        cartasrojas[cartasrojas.length] = cartas[i];
    } else {
        cartasnegras[cartasnegras.length] = cartas[i];
   }
}
"12p"
cartasrojasypares = []
[]
for (var i = 0; i < cartasrojas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartasrojas[i][0] %2===0 || cartas[i][1] %2===0 ){
        cartasrojasypares[cartasrojasypares.length] = cartasrojas[i];
    } 
}
    console.log(cartasrojasypares[cartasrojasypares.length-1])
VM3280:6 12d
undefined
cartasrojasypares
(12) ["2c", "4c", "6c", "8c", "10c", "12c", "2d", "4d", "6d", "8d", "10d", "12d"]
cartasrojas
(24) ["1c", "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "10c", "11c", "12c", "1d", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "10d", "11d", "12d"]
cartasnegras
(24) ["1t", "2t", "3t", "4t", "5t", "6t", "7t", "8t", "9t", "10t", "11t", "12t", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"]
```

Me quedo bien, pero me pedia en realidad que utilizara diccionarios u objetos, tema que tengo poco o nada claro, ahora estoy intentando realizarlo de dicha manera, por lo que llegue al siguiente codigo, tengo un array cartas vacio, un array con los palos de la carta, creo los objetos y guardo el resultado en cartas y me quedan las cartas, lo que no se es como hacer el filtrado que necesito, 1-por un lado cartas rojas y negras, 2-de las cartas rojas sacar las pares e imprimir la ultima carta

```html
var cartas = [];

var palo = ["c","d","t","p"];

for (var i = 0; i < palo.length; i = i + 1) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1) {
        cartas[cartas.length] = { palo: palo[ i ], valor: j };
      }
    }

cartasrojas = []

cartasnegras = []

for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartas[i].palo === "c" || cartas[i].palo === "d") {
        cartasrojas[cartasrojas.length] = cartas[i];
    } else {
       if (cartas[i].palo === "t" || cartas[i].palo === "p") {
        cartasnegras[cartasnegras.length] = cartas[i];
   }
}
}

cartasrojasypares = []

for (var i = 0; i < cartasrojas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartasrojas[i].valor%2 === 0 ) {
        cartasrojasypares[cartasrojasypares.length] = cartasrojas[i];
    }
}

console.log(cartasrojasypares[cartasrojasypares.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes.

Los atributos o funciones de un objeto se acceden mediante el operador `.`. De hecho, ya usas algunos en tu código `console.log`, `cartasrojas.length`, etc.

Una vez que defines un objeto con un atributo `cartas[cartas.length] = { p: palo[ i ], v: j };`, simplemente haces lo mismo `console.log(cartas[0].p)`<sup>1</sup>.

Por ejemplo, para sacar la última carta.

```js
    var cartas = [];
    var palo = ["c","d","t","p"];
    for (var i = 0; i < palo.length; i = i + 1) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1) {
        cartas[cartas.length] = { palo: palo[ i ], valor: j };
      }
    }
    var ultimaCartaRoja;
    for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
       var carta = cartas[i];
       if (carta.palo == "c" || carta.palo == "d"){
           // Es una carta roja
           if (carta.valor % 2 == 0) {
              // Es par
              ultimaCartaRoja = carta;
           }
       }
    } 
    console.log(ultimaCartaRoja);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Siempre conviene usar identificadores que den información de qué significa el valor, aunque sean un poco más largos. En el ejemplo he cambiado `p` y `v` por `palo` y `valor`, que se leen mucho mejor.

Comment: gracias @SJuan76 , reedite el post con la solucion, quiza no es el codigo mas limpio o estructurado pero pienso que para el poco conocimiento que tengo y lo que me esta costando esta llendo bastante bien